# SpringBoot Creating DynamicDataSource : Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

```
@Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.master")
public DataSource masterDataSource() {
    DruidDataSource dataSource = new DruidDataSource();
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "slaveDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.slave")
public DataSource slaveDataSource() {
    DruidDataSource dataSource = new DruidDataSource();
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "dynamicDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource,
                             @Qualifier("slaveDataSource") DataSource slaveDataSource) {
    DynamicDataSource dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource();
    Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
    dataSourceMap.put("masterDataSource", masterDataSource);
    dataSourceMap.put("slaveDataSource", slaveDataSource);
    dynamicDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
    dynamicDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource);
    return dynamicDataSource;
}
```

this is my code to create dynamic datasource, but it seems to have something wrong

```
Error creating bean with name 'dynamicDataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Is there an unresolvable circular reference? How can I fix it ?

thx for your answer!

Comment: Kindly upload complete error logs

Comment: Add @DependsOn({"masterDataSource", "slaveDataSource"}) to public DataSource dataSource...

Comment: @Afridi thank you so much, it's working now.
But, I just don't understand why there is circular reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in your case, `dynamicDataSource` creation is dependent on other 2 beans `slaveDataSource`& `masterDataSource`. So you need to add `@DependsOn` on bean `dynamicDataSource` which instruct Spring that creation of bean `dynamicDataSource` is dependent on other 2 beans as well.

So your updated configuration should look like this:

```
@DependsOn({"masterDataSource", "slaveDataSource"})
@Bean(name = "dynamicDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(@Autowired @Qualifier("masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource, @Autowired @Qualifier("slaveDataSource") DataSource slaveDataSource) {
    DynamicDataSource dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource();
    Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
    dataSourceMap.put("masterDataSource", masterDataSource);
    dataSourceMap.put("slaveDataSource", slaveDataSource);
    dynamicDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
    dynamicDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource);
    return dynamicDataSource;
}
```

### Updated

According to [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html),

> Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are
>   guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. Used
>   infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on
>   another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather
>   depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.

Or for further info, check this [Why @DependsOn has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178735/why-did-spring-ignore-my-dependson-annotation)

Comment: `@Bean(name = "dynamicTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager masterTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dynamicDataSource") DataSource dynamicDataSource)`

`dynamicTransactionManager` creation is depentdent on `dynamicDataSource` bean, but we don't need to add `@DependsOn("dynamicDataSource")`. It confused me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning @Order on top of the beans may resolve this issue.
Like you can mention @Order(1),@Order(2)

or  check the logs by setting the log level to debug in application.properties