# Spring @ContextConfiguration Enforce order?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-config

I have written some Configuration classes in Spring (4.1.7) to make writing some standard stuff (e.g. Testcases) easier. For this, I used `@Condition` to check, for example, if there already is a `DataSource` defined, if not, create a new in-memory one. This is, of course, bascially what Spring Boot already offers - but since we don't have Spring Boot in that application yet, this is not an option for us there.

The whole thing works very well, if you write, for example...

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4Runner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( classes = {SomeTest.Config.class, DefaultConfig.class} )
public class SomeTest {

    static class Config {

       ...
```

In this case, first the static `Config` class is read, the beans there are created and then `DefaultConfig` is looked at and instantiates, for example, a `DataSource`, if `Config` did not.

The problem I have with this solution is, that it contains an implicit knowledge: You need to know that you have to write the more specific configuration class first in your `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. If you put `DefaultConfig` first, it will check that one first and since, for example, no `DataSource` was yet created, it will create one, which can lead to unfortunate side effects (since some stuff depending on a `DataSource` are also created there, for example).

I would really like to make this more stable by enforcing that `DefaultConfig` is ALWAYS loaded as the last configuration (without having to explicitly putting it last in the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation). So, if a developer messes the whole ordering up, nothing bad happens and everything still works as planned, since `DefaultConfig` is loaded last and only then checks if everyone else already defined a `DataSource`, for example.

Is there any way to achieve this? What I need is simply the Spring Boot behavior, where Auto-Configure classes are **automatically** processed **last**. 
Obviously `@Order` does not work there, since it is not intended for Configuration class ordering... Is there some class one can override to influence the behavior there?

Comment: You could try `@Order` annotation on your configuration classes. Classes with lower value for `@Order` should be loaded first

Comment: @Ivan Unfortunately, no. As I already mentioned, `@Order` does not work for Configuration classes (at least not in 4.1.7, see also the Javadoc there : "Annotation-based ordering is supported for specific kinds of components only,[..]")

Comment: You could also try `@DependsOn` to mark (any) bean in your `DefaultConfig` `@DependsOn("dataSource")` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178735/why-did-spring-ignore-my-dependson-annotation. Maybe that will help

Comment: @Ivan This will also not work, since the Configuration the `DefaultConfig` depends on is dynamic (one per test/module/whatever). And making `DefaultConfig` depend on `DateSource` is a bad idea, since `DefaultConfig` provides a `DataSource` when loaded first, thus fullfilling the DependsOn requirement.